# createProcess Restart when closed/crashed

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to know how would i restart a program that i have created with CreateProcess.
I need the program to restart if its closed or if it crashed

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE ghJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL); // GLOBAL
    if (ghJob == NULL)
        ::MessageBox(0, "Could not create job object", "TEST", MB_OK);
    else {
        JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION jeli = { 0 };

        // Configure all child processes associated with the job to terminate when the
        jeli.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
        if (0 == SetInformationJobObject(ghJob, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &jeli, sizeof(jeli)))
            ::MessageBox(0, "Could not SetInformationJobObject", "TEST", MB_OK);
    }

    STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    char cmdArgs[] = "notepad.exe";

    // Launch child process - example is notepad.exe
    if (::CreateProcess(NULL, cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)) {

        ::MessageBox(0, "CreateProcess succeeded.", "TEST", MB_OK);
        if (ghJob) {
            if (0 == AssignProcessToJobObject(ghJob, processInfo.hProcess))
                ::MessageBox(0, "Could not AssignProcessToObject", "TEST", MB_OK);
        }

        WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        //Restart process  here if its closed

        CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess); 
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code in a cycle. `WaitForSingleObject` waits till child process exits, `CloseHandle` calls are closing the handles and the child process code is running another time. I've created an eternal cycle, so this program will never exit. Add exiting conditions to this cycle according to your requirements, for example a `MessageBox` asking if it should exit or run another time

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  HANDLE ghJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL); // GLOBAL
  if (ghJob == NULL)
    ::MessageBox(0, "Could not create job object", "TEST", MB_OK);
  else {
    JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION jeli = { 0 };

    // Configure all child processes associated with the job to terminate when the
    jeli.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
    if (0 == SetInformationJobObject(ghJob, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &jeli, sizeof(jeli)))
      ::MessageBox(0, "Could not SetInformationJobObject", "TEST", MB_OK);
  }

  STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
  PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
  char cmdArgs[] = "notepad.exe";

  // Launch child process - example is notepad.exe
  do
  {
    if (::CreateProcess(NULL, cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)) {

      ::MessageBox(0, "CreateProcess succeeded.", "TEST", MB_OK);
      if (ghJob) {
        if (0 == AssignProcessToJobObject(ghJob, processInfo.hProcess))
          ::MessageBox(0, "Could not AssignProcessToObject", "TEST", MB_OK);
      }

      WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
      //Restart process  here if its closed

      CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    }
  } while (1);

  return 0;
}
```